# Alphabetical sorting - local language

Tags: localization

I want to sort posts by alphabet in local language (croatian language).

So letter Đ should come after D but now it goes in the end, after Z.
Some letters (like Č and Ć) should come after C, but currently Wordpress is sorting them like they all are under C.

I am using localized Wordpress version (4.0.1–hr) and the query for fetching is

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'category_name' => $slug, 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'title'
    ) );
```

Comment: What value are you using for `DB_COLLATE`?

Comment: I use the `Ðð` chars in my language (Icelandic) and by using the correct collation (as @toscho suggests) you can fix the ordering. I use `utf8_icelandic_ci` and I guess there exists something similar for your language?

Comment: Use `utf8_unicode_ci`, that covers most languages. Never use `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: So you guy think this is a DB issuse, intrestin ;) - didnt think about that...

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work:

In `wpconfig.php` file I set

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_croatian_ci');
```

Do an SQL query on database in PhpMyadmin with:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci
```

I tried setting with `utf8_unicode_ci` first, sorting was slightly better but not quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If Wordpress is installed in your language, that shouldn't be a problem.

You are missing the order parameter:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name'     => $slug, 
    'paged'             => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'orderby'           => 'title',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Hope this helps, always best to check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: I did check the codex, 'order' has default value for DESC so it is not needed. Either way, if i put it in everything is the same and it doesnt address the issue. But thank you for your time

Comment: yep, tought your having a simpler issuse but its seems this a problem with mixing english with other language ;( - does the post slug aka orderby=>name - isnt applicable? What characters apear in the slug? - in any case, sorry i could help further  -trying to research this more...